# Line integral example

Tags: real-analysis, integration, curves

Consider the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Denote the curve by $\gamma(t)$, $t\in [a,b]$. Compute
$$ \int_\gamma f dl:=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt,$$
where $f(x,y)=x+y$.

I got a parameterization for each one of the sides: $\gamma_1(t)=(t,0)$, $\gamma_2(t)=(t,1-t)$ and $\gamma_3(t)=(0,t)$, for $t\in [0,1]$, and I used $$\int_\gamma f dl=\int_{\gamma_1} f dl+\int_{\gamma_2} f dl+\int_{\gamma_3} f dl=1/2+\sqrt{2}+1/2=1+\sqrt{2}.$$
Is this correct? Does the value of the integral depend on whether we move along the curve clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's wrong. $\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$ is not a closed path.

Comment: Replace $\gamma_1$ by $\gamma_1(t) = (1-t,0)$. Then it's fine. However, the result is the same.

Comment: @amsmath I wrote that $\int_\gamma=\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\gamma_3}$, not that $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$ (this latter statement is not true, as you wrote). The integral $\int_{\gamma_i}$ does not depend on the orientation of $\gamma_i$, right? Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Correct, it does not depend on the orientation. That's waht also jmerry wrote in their answer.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: I'll also note that it's good practice to always line up the subpaths so that, for example, $\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$. If we do it consistently on this sort of integral, we'll have the right habits when it actually matters.

Comment: @amsmath I would like to ask you a question. My professor says that, if we consider the triangle counterclockwise, then $\gamma_1(t)=(t,0)$, $t\in [0,1]$; $\gamma_2(t)=(t,1-t)$, $t\in [1,0]$; and $\gamma_3(t)=(0,t)$, $t\in [1,0]$, so that $\int_\gamma f dl=1/2-\sqrt{2}-1/2=-\sqrt{2}$. But these computations do not make sense, right? Because the parameterizations for $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ are not correct. Moreover, $\int_\gamma fdl$ has the interpretation of the area under $f>0$ through the curve, so it must be positive. Am I right? Should the result be $1+\sqrt{2}$ as I wrote?

Comment: @jxm Whatever function and path you choose, the result for the reversed path is the same: Let $f$ be a function and $\gamma$ a path (not necessarily closed), parametrized over $[0,1]$. Then the reversed path is given by $\delta(t) = \gamma(1-t)$. Hence$$\int_\delta f\,dl = \int_0^1f(\gamma(1-t))|\gamma'(1-t)|\,dt = -\int_1^0 f(\gamma(s))|\gamma'(s)|\,ds = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(s))|\gamma'(s)|\,ds = \int_\gamma f\,dl.$$So, where do these minuses come from in your calculation?

Comment: @amsmath The professor said that, since $\gamma_3(t)=(0,t)$, $t\in [1,0]$, then $$\int_{\gamma_3} fdl=\int_1^0 f(\gamma_3(t))|\gamma_3'(t)|dt=\int_1^0 t dt=-\frac12.$$ But the definition of $\gamma_3$ is not correct, since $[1,0]$ is nothing... I think he was thinking on the reversed path, which should be $\gamma_3(t)=(0,1-t)$, $t\in [0,1]$. It does not make sense to reverse $[0,1]$ to $[1,0]$... For $\gamma_2$, he did a similar thing: $\gamma_2(t)=(t,1-t)$, $t\in[1,0]$, so $\int_{\gamma_2} f dl=\int_1^0 f(t,1-t)|\gamma_2'(t)|dt=-\sqrt{2}$. But again, that's not the correct curve...

Comment: @jxm So, it seems your professor doesn't know the stuff he is teaching pretty well. He's definitely wrong. As you said, $[1,0]$ is nonsense. Of course he means the reversed path, but then he has to define it correctly. Then he'll see that the result is the same.

Comment: @amsmath Ok, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @jxm Send him this: https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/122-youre-doing-it-wrong :D

Comment: @amsmath lol XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct, but the process isn't entirely correct. If we name the vertices $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, and $C=(0,1)$, your path runs from $A$ to $B$ ($\gamma_1$), from $C$ to $B$ $(\gamma_2)$, and then from $A$ to $C$ $(\gamma_3)$. This is not a closed path; we need to reverse one or more of the paths to make it into one. Guessing your intent, I'd reverse $\gamma_2$ to $(1-t,t)$ and $\gamma_3$ to $(0,1-t)$.

This scalar version of the line integral doesn't depend on which direction we traverse the path in, because there's what amounts to an absolute value in the arclength differential $dl$. And that's what saved us; that same direction-independence applies to the subpaths $\gamma_i$ we built this out of, so reversing one of them doesn't change its integral.

A vector-type line integral $\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{f}\cdot \mathbf{dl}$ would depend on the direction; those integrals are generally more useful, but that's not what was asked about in this problem.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong, the second is correct. ;-)

Comment: Ah, yes. The paths aren't written in a closed way. Correction incoming.

Comment: @jmerry  I would like to ask you a question. My professor says that, if we consider the triangle counterclockwise, then $\gamma_1(t)=(t,0)$, $t\in [0,1]$; $\gamma_2(t)=(t,1-t)$, $t\in [1,0]$; and $\gamma_3(t)=(0,t)$, $t\in [1,0]$, so that $\int_\gamma f dl=1/2-\sqrt{2}-1/2=-\sqrt{2}$. But these computations do not make sense, right? Because the parameterizations for $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ are not correct. Moreover, $\int_\gamma fdl$ has the interpretation of the area under $f>0$ through the curve, so it must be positive. Am I right? Should the result be $1+\sqrt{2}$ as I wrote?

Comment: Note what your professor wrote for $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$: $t\in [1,0]$. That's an empty interval. It's supposed to be $\int_1^0 *\,dt$, but that interpretation is wrong for an arclength integral. Yes, your calculation is correct.